# integrate PHPExcel withe ZendFramework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I try to use both libraries  PHPWord and PHPExcel as two libraries in ZendFramework2 
that is to say put them in /lib of Zend Framework 2 and load them into my controller with

in my autoload.php i put the following

```
<?php

// autoload.php generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit689ffe38af096b92264c8f237441d64e::getLoader();

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->autoloadernamespaces[] = "Excel_";
$loader->registerNamespace('Excel_');

$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

if ($configSection == 'development')
{
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
}
```

my Controller is :

```
<?php
namespace Auth\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Excel\PHPExcel;



class AuthController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function LoginAction()
{
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$document = $objPHPExcel->load('example1.xls');

echo date('H:i:s') , " Données Ajoutées Avec Succés" ;
$document->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Mike')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'Spils);
        // Save Excel5 file



$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($document, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));



}
}
```

`
but the classe is not being load

i get the following error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Auth\Controller\PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5' not found in         C:\wamp\www\zend\module\Auth\src\Auth\Controller\AuthController.php on line 14
```

any one can help me pleeeeaase ?

Comment: Do not add to the Zend Framework default library. This may cause you problems in future updates. Create a module separate in your application and integrate PHPExcel there.

Comment: You are using ZF2? Please include PHP Excel via Composer: `"CodePlex/PHPExcel": "dev-master"` - this will take care of autoloading setup for you, too!

Comment: why are you returning ComposerAutoloaderInit689ffe38af096b92264c8f237441d64e ? doesn't make sense in that context..

Answer (score 7):

If you are using composer to load zendframework, try to load phpExcel lib too using composer.php.

Run following command from command line in project folder:

```bash
php composer.phar selfupdate

php composer.phar require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Access in controller method as:

```php
$excelObj = new \PHPExcel();
```

It works for me.

Comment: You saved me hours or propably days mate! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "classic" Skeleton

Download the library (in MyApp/vendor/library/ for example) 
The website is : http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

The architecture of PHPExcel is made with prefixes (like zf1), so for me, it's easier to use the "Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader" like this : 
modify the file autoload_classmap of your module

```
<?php
return array('PHPExcel'=>__DIR__.'/../../vendor/library/PhpExcel/PHPExcel.php',);
```

And so you can use :

```
$excel = new \PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have any experience with ZF2. But I am pretty sure you're registering a wrong namespace, it should be:

```
$loader->autoloadernamespaces[] = "PHPExcel_";
$loader->registerNamespace('PHPExcel_');
```

<strike>**EDIT**</strike>

Do you have your PHPExcel library in `Zend/Excel/PHPExcel` at this location?

Well again I am not sure but, it shouldn't be placed inside Zend's core library.

```
use PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5;
```

It should be placed parallel to Zend's library perhaps.

```
- Zend/    
- PHPExcel/
```

**EDIT 2**

If this is how Zendframework 2 folder structure is:

```
- vendor/
    - zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend
    - PHPExcel/
    - autoload.php
```

Perhaps this should be the location to have your `PHPExcel` library I think

Comment: Thank you i correct my autoload.php  but i still get the same error

Comment: I put the folder PHPExcel in the same level us Zend the folder 's name is PHPExcel and it has inside it PHPexcel.php and Classes .i also use HPExcel\Reader\Excel5 in my controller and still got this error. sorry  but belive me i did every logic and illogic thing to get it work but without result !

Comment: no , the defaut location of autoloder is in         C:\wamp\www\zend\vendor\autoload.php but others files are right as you said , i tried to move auload.php in the same level us PHPExcel and Zend but no result

Comment: @Ramy1988 you must not move autoload.php file, you are to move PHPExcel library instead. Any 3rd party libraries added should be at Vendor/ location. well that's just a general knowledge. Either you can wait for any other answer or wait for me to setup ZF2 for the first time :)

Comment: thank you for your help i still trying to get it work and also i appriciate any kind of help . if i solve this "wired " probleme i will post the answer. thanks a lot for your time

Comment: i already installed zendframework 2 and i made a small tutorial but it is in french .

Comment: you mean it is solved for you? can you pass me the link, I am assuming you cannot add your answer already by your SO reputation.

Comment: no the problem is not solved yet , but as you said that you will setup ZF2 i think that my tutorial will help you , give your email so i can send it to you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ro-ko, you should place the folder in vendor, so

```
vendor/PHPExcel
```

Then open up vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

You'll see something like this

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
);
```

Simply add you namespace and the path to that array, eg...

```
return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
    'PHPExcel\\' => $vendorDir . '/PHPExcel/',
);
```

Comment: still got the same error :(   i placed PHPExcel folder (wittch contains PHPExcel.php and the folder Classes) in /Vendor then i added the name space as you suggested.i notice that the class  PHPExcel.php has no namespace and i called it like this :         use PHPExcel\PHPExcel;                                                use PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5; can the absence of the name space be the cause of my probleme ?

Comment: I'd say having no namespace at all would be a problem, yes.

Comment: You do know there's a composer package for it? https://packagist.org/packages/CodePlex/PHPExcel

Comment: yes , i downloaded it via github and it gives me the hole library with the folders exemples ,build,Classes,Documentation,unittests, vendor) but i'm only using the folder Classes as a library , i notice that the library PHPExcel has an autoload file and autoload_namespaces.php and others configuartion and loading files , should i use them or it is not necessary(ussually the ZF auloader did all the loading steps no ?)

Comment: don't download via github, install it with composer `composer.phar require CodePlex/PhpExcel` (when it asks for the version constraint type `dev-master`)

Comment: done ! i edited composer.json by adding  {
    "require": {
        "CodePlex/PHPExcel": "1.7.8"
    }
} and the download ends , now would please tell me when can i find the library PHPExcel and just a small idea haw to use ? thanks a lot

Comment: oh my God !!!! i getting crazy here  :(( i downloaded PHPExcel with composer and it is located in C:\wamp\www\zend\vendor\CodePlex\PHPExcel, and i used in my controller like this   use use PHPEXcel\PHPExcel;  and still the same error !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: did you clean up all the other stuff you previously added to try and fix it?

Comment: i did better , i reinstall zendskeleton application and zf2 (i started again from zero) and always the same error , i'm starting to think that this is a bug in zf2 !! it is not logic to be so hard to integrate an external library !!!!!

Comment: Then I'm stumped, on a clean install of skeleton app, followed by install of the PHPExcel package, I can instantiate a PHPExcel class in a controller just by typing `$excel = new \PHPExcel;`

Comment: sorry , the same probleme ! can send to me your controller.php , i'm trying every thing to solve this

Comment: It's the default Application\Index\IndexController, with that one line in indexAction, followed by an `echo get_class($excel)` to verify it's what I expected. No magic. Are you sure the web server has access to the newly created vendor\CodePlex folder and all it's sub folders/files

Comment: that depends on your OS and web server, but it's off topic for this question, try searching for your os name, your server and file permissions on SO eg `ubuntu apache file permissions`

Comment: ok i will make some reseachers then i will back to you , any way thanks a lot for your time and for your help .hope i can solve this soon . thanks

Comment: hello , i still searching a solution for my probleme but i strongly thikn that's a probleme of namespaces because when deleteing namespaces from my controller it works !  should i give a namespace to all classes in PHPExcel library to be found by the autoloader ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem in ZF2.

Added this to

> /vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces:

```
'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/PHPExcel/'),
```

And in the controller instantiate the class:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to autoload PHPExcel classes. The `vendor/autoload.php` file it’s an auto-generated file. The implication is "don’t edit this file and expect your changes to stick".
In alternative, to avoid to have problems with autoload PHPExcel classes, is available an easy integration of [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library into zend framework 2, using the zf2 module [MvlabsPHPExcel](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsPHPExcel).

After that you need to enable the `MvlabsPHPExcel` module:

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        // ...
        'MvlabsPHPExcel',            
    ],
    // ...
];
```

And after that you be able to use inside the controller.

```
$phpExcelObject = $this->serviceLocator->get('mvlabs.phpexcel.service')->createPHPExcelObject();
```